# Oracle SQL - Using SysDate to create a specific date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to automate a report that will always the first day of the current month and year in the WHERE caluses.

"YYYY-MM-01"

I am trying to achieve the following but sadly, I can't get anything to work using To_Char/ To_Date/SysDate.

```
    to_date(SYSDATE('YYYY-MM') + '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Thank you

Comment: So you just want the first day of the current month?

Comment: I don't have an Oracle box here to test but `SYSDATE` [does not accept parameters](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/sysdate.php). You should be getting an error message :-?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Both proposed solution by (Joe / Gordon Linoff) are working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the first day of the current month (as a `DATE`), simply:

```
trunc(sysdate,'MON')
```

or, formatted:

```
to_char(trunc(sysdate,'MON'),'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

The string concatenation operator in Oracle is `||`, not `+`.  And `SYSDATE` is a constant not a function:

```
to_date(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM') || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

By the way, you can also do this calculation as:

```
trunc(sysdate - extract(day from sysdate) + 1)
```

That is, subtract the day of the month and add one.  That way, you don't have to mess with fiddly date/character formats.